# JavaScript proper return type on Exception that is not really an error

Tags: javascript, exception, return-type

## What I have done

I have written a function, that persists a state of an object using `JSON.stringify` and inserts the string into a mongodb collection.

If this succeeds, the function returns the `_id` of the inserted document.

If the insert fails it either re-throws the error (if any) or throws itself an error, that no document has been inserted.

I am also creating a hash using sha256 before inserting to the collection in order to verify integrity after restore but also to check if there is already the exact same state persisted.

## My Problem

Now if the state has already been persisted I don't want to save it again but respond that the operation has failed. But this bothers me as due to the following reasons:

#### a) return faley value

If I return a falsey value then my function returns two different value types (Boolean on hash duplicate, String as insert result) plus throws Errors.

#### b) throw an Error

If I throw an Error, then I will have to wrap some more complex exception handling around this method. This seems to be the obvious solution. But in terms of my application is not really an Error. The process of persisting has just been "skipped". The other errors however will be a definite Error as the app relies on a state which had not been persisted succesfully.

#### c) return a String message

I could return a message to ensure that always the same datatype (String) is returned but I have never seen that before and matching against strings as return values makes things the same complicated as handling many different types of errors.

Is there another option I have not mentioned?

## Some Code

For those who may require some code, the function looks (pseudo-ish) like the following:

```
function persist(state) {
  const stateStr = JSON.stringify(state);
  const stateHash = SHA256(stateStr);

  if (States.findOne({ hash: stateHash }) {
    // a) return false or null
    // b) throw Error
    // c) return String message
  }

  const insertId = States.insert({ state: stateStr, hash: stateHash });
  if (!insertId) {
    throw new Error('insert failed');
  }
  return insertId;
}
```

Note: don't mind sync/async here, please. Technically this method is working fine. I have just no proper solution for a return type when a hash already exists.

Comment: we don't know where this function is called or what you are doing with the returned `id`, but i see nothing wrong for a function to return a different type (`false`) on failure. It's actually similar to a string message but will be easier to test the result. Those 2 solutions seem better to me than throw an error (as it's actually not really an error, and i think `try..catch` should be reserved to cases you can't avoid it).

Comment: Ask yourself why you want to return this message, is there any reason to say that it hasn't been inserted because it already exists or are you doing this 'just because'. If the record fails to insert, what are you going to do with the information that it's failed to insert?

Comment: <Micheal Curry> - If it failed but was required the executing user will be informed while the fail due to an existing state-hash should fail "silent" to the user and currently there is no intention to log this failure. 
<Kaddath> - The insertId is only used in my tests to verify the exact document. However your both comments made me think that I could instead return the hash instead, since the hashes are (should be) unique enough to verify the document insert in the tests, too. Any thoughts on that?